# String was not recognized while converting Date Format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datetime

How to convert "dd/mm/yyyy" to "yyyy-mm-dd" format.
I've tried it like this:

```
 DateTime dtInputDate = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text); //txtDate.Text = "19/07/2012"
 string strOutputDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
 dtInputDate.ToString(strOutputDateFormat);
 txtDate.Text = dtInputDate.ToShortDateString();
```

but got an error:
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Parse Exact, and specify the format, as `"d/M/yyyy"`

```
 string strDate = "19/07/2012";
 DateTime dtInputDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //txtDate.Text = 
 string strOutputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
 Console.Write(dtInputDate.ToString(strOutputDateFormat));
 strDate = dtInputDate.ToString(strOutputDateFormat);
```

Edit: Here replace `strDate` with `txtDate.Text` for your code

Comment: Dear, did you try it ? Because, on my side it is returning "19/07/2012 12:00:00 AM".

Comment: `dtInputDate` will hold the value you specified, `strDate` will hold `"2012-07-19"`

Comment: @Itz.Irshad, DateTime variable will hold the value, irrespective of the format, format only matters for displaying as well as parsing input

Answer (score 3):

Date format should be :

```
string strOutputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

To parse a string to date use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method and [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: Good Point. But, it show error on first line where I'm parsing txtDate.text to DateTime. It didn't recognize "19/07/2012" as valid date.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see how that goes, date formats are case sensitive:

```
string strOutputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Also the third and fourth lines of your code don't do anything useful! You need to replace both with:

```
txtDate.Text = dtInputDate.ToString(strOutputDateFormat);
```

`dtInputDate.ToString(strOutputDateFormat);` is returning a value, but you aren't assigning this value to any variable, and `dtInputDate.ToShortDateString();` won't output your date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

If the first line of your code is throwing an error then make sure that `txtDate.Text` actually contains "19/07/2012" and that you haven't put this into another textbox, and check that the textbox you think is named `txtDate.Text` actually is!

Hope this helps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Well, it show error on first line where I'm parsing txtDate.text to DateTime. It didn't recognize "19/07/2012" as valid date.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code.

```
DateTime dtInputDate = DateTime.Parse(this.txtDate.Text); 

this.txtDate.Text = dtInputDate.ToString(String.Format("yyyy-MM-dd", dtInputDate.ToShortDateString()));
```

[image: Output][image]

Comment: Same error on very first line **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: check above the screen shots you will see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Trye something like

```
DateTime dtInputDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",null,DateTimeStyles.None);
string strOutputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
txtDate.Text = dtInputDate.ToString(strOutputDateFormat);
```

[DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

[DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038)

or even

[DateTime.TryParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime%)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be somthing like

```
txtDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```